# string to array, split by single and double quotes

Tags: php, preg-split

i'm trying to use php to split a string into array components using either `"` or `'` as the delimiter. i just want to split by the outermost string. here are four examples and the desired result for each:

```
$pattern = "?????";
$str = "the cat 'sat on' the mat";
$res = preg_split($pattern, $str);
print_r($res);
/*output:
Array
(
    [0] => the cat 
    [1] => 'sat on'
    [2] =>  the mat
)*/

$str = "the cat \"sat on\" the mat";
$res = preg_split($pattern, $str);
print_r($res);
/*output:
Array
(
    [0] => the cat 
    [1] => "sat on"
    [2] =>  the mat
)*/

$str = "the \"cat 'sat' on\" the mat";
$res = preg_split($pattern, $str);
print_r($res);
/*output:
Array
(
    [0] => the
    [1] => "cat 'sat' on"
    [2] =>  the mat
)*/

$str = "the 'cat \"sat\" on' the mat 'when \"it\" was' seventeen";
$res = preg_split($pattern, $str);
print_r($res);
/*output:
Array
(
    [0] => the
    [1] => 'cat "sat" on'
    [2] =>  the mat
    [3] => 'when "it" was'
    [4] =>  seventeen
)*/
```

as you can see i only want to split by the outermost quotation, and i want to ignore any quotations within quotations.

the closest i have come up with for `$pattern` is

```
$pattern = "/((?P<quot>['\"])[^(?P=quot)]*?(?P=quot))/";
```

but obviously this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` with the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option. The regular expressions is not quite as elegant as @Jan Turoň's back reference approach because the required capture group messes up the results.

```
$str = "the 'cat \"sat\" on' the mat the \"cat 'sat' on\" the mat";
$match = preg_split("/('[^']*'|\"[^\"]*\")/U", $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: I believe your solution is more elegant. +1

Comment: that was what i was after. its surprising it didn't need back-references, but great!

Comment: if i want to extend the regex to ignore escaped quotes will that be easy? for example `$str = "the 'cat s\'at on' the mat"` should give `[0] => the , [1] => 'cat s\'at on', [2] =>  the mat`. if not then i will add a fresh new question for this. cheers!

Comment: `"/('(?:.*)(?<!\\\\)(?>\\\\\\\\)*'|\"(?:.*)(?<!\\\\)(?>\\\\\\\\)*\")/U"` - Yes, all those backslashes are required.

Comment: That will allow backslash-escaped quotes. A double backslash will NOT escape a quote, but will be a literal backslash. You will have to remove the extras after splitting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `preg_match` for this:

```
$str = "the \"cat 'sat' on\" the mat";
$pattern = '/^([^\'"]*)(([\'"]).*\3)(.*)$/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
  printf("[initial] => %s\n[quoted] => %s\n[end] => %s\n",
     $matches[1],
     $matches[2],
     $matches[4]
  );
}
```

This prints:

```
[initial] => the 
[quoted] => "cat 'sat' on"
[end] =>  the mat
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

- `/^([^\'"]*)` => put the initial bit until the first quote (either single or double) in the first captured group
- `(([\'"]).*\3)` => capture in \2 the text corresponding from the initial quote (either single or double) (that is captured in \3) until the closing quote (that must be the same type as the opening quote, hence the \3). The fact that the regexp is greedy by nature helps to get from the first quote to the last one, regardless of how many quotes are inside.
- `(.*)$/` => Capture until the end in \4

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution using [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
$result1 = array();
function parser($p) {
  global $result1;
  $result1[] = $p[0];
  return "|"; // temporary delimiter
}

$str = "the 'cat \"sat\" on' the mat 'when \"it\" was' seventeen";
$str = preg_replace_callback("/(['\"]).*\\1/U", "parser", $str);
$result2 = explode("|",$str); // using temporary delimiter
```

Now you can zip those arrays using `array_map`

```
$result = array();
function zipper($a,$b) {
  global $result;
  if($a) $result[] = $a;
  if($b) $result[] = $b;
}
array_map("zipper",$result2,$result1);
print_r($result);
```

And the result is

```
[0] => the 
[1] => 'cat "sat" on'
[2] =>  the mat 
[3] => 'when "it" was'
[4] =>  seventeen
```

**Note:** I'd would be probably better to create a class doing this feat, so the global variables can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [back references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) and [ungreedy modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in `preg_match_all`

```
$str = "the 'cat \"sat\" on' the mat 'when \"it\" was' seventeen";
preg_match_all("/(['\"])(.*)\\1/U", $str, $match);
print_r($match[0]);
```

Now you have your outermost quotation parts

```
[0] => 'cat "sat" on'
[1] => 'when "it" was'
```

And you can find the rest of the string with `substr` and `strpos` (kind of blackbox solution)

```
$a = $b = 0; $result = array();
foreach($match[0] as $part) {
  $b = strpos($str,$part);
  $result[] = substr($str,$a,$b-$a);
  $result[] = $part;
  $a = $b+strlen($part);
}
$result[] = substr($str,$a);
print_r($result);
```

Here is the result

```
[0] => the 
[1] => 'cat "sat" on'
[2] =>  the mat 
[3] => 'when "it" was'
[4] =>  seventeen
```

Just strip eventual empty heading/trailing element if the quotation is at the very beginning/end of the string.

Comment: that does work, but it doesn't return the bits outside the match, which i do need

Comment: it is a possible solution. if nobody comes up with a single regex method then i will award the answer. but i would prefer a single regex as it would be simpler.

Comment: I updated my solution to include the bits outside the match, is it ok?

Comment: it does what i'm after, but i would still prefer a one line regular expression. anyway, thanks for this solution - if nobody posts a one line solution then i will award this one the tick :)