# PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I use netbeans, I try to replace `\`  with `\\` but it fails , it can't escape the `\\` character.

This is not a Netbeans issue , it's a PHP issue .

```
preg_replace('\','\\','text to \ be parsed');
```

Any sollutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use 4 backslashes and please don't forget the delimiters:

`echo echo preg_replace('~\\\\~','\\\\\\\\','text to \\ be parsed');`

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/40334)

**Explanation:** When PHP parse `\\\\` it will escape `\\` two times, which means it becomes `\\`, now when PHP passes it to the regex engine, it will receive `\\` which means `\`.

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian I provided an online demo with some explanation to remove all the doubts. We're talking about regex.

Comment: Yep, good catch - it works, and the explanation now makes it clear. +1

Comment: regex is ok also, chr also, take the one solution that you want

Comment: but, if only 1 char needs to be ascaped, i recomend chr function

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian Well I hope this is a simplified version of the actual regex, otherwise a simple `str_replace()` would do the job. Why I don't like the `chr(92)` technique is because you will have an ugly concatenation in the actual regex. Although this is just a preference :)

Comment: c'est la vie; i assumed that he does not understand regex yet

Answer (score 2):

Try the php `chr()` function and tell the preg_replace the char ascii code for `\` and `\\`.

[chr function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_chr.asp)

[ascii code table](http://www.lookuptables.com/)

```
<?php
echo chr(52) . "<br>"; // Decimal value
echo chr(052) . "<br>"; // Octal value
echo chr(0x52) . "<br>"; // Hex value

preg_replace(chr(1),chr(2),'text'),

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works: (using str_replace() rather than preg_replace())

```
$str = "text to \ be parsed";

$str = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $str);

echo $str;
```