# Need to match multiple backslahes in a PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to match 4 backslahes using preg_match.

`preg_match('/\\\\\\\\/',$subject)` works fine, but `preg_match('/\\{4}/',$subject)` doesn't.

Perhaps I'm using {} incorrectly. Could anyone advise?

Comment: Hmm it works fine for me, http://regexr.com/391nd

Comment: stange. i'm getting 0 rtned in php. maybe its a php thing?

Comment: You are right, in php it is not working. Somehow the second backslash escapes the `{`

Comment: You need 4 backslashes to match 1 backslash. I explained this in a previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18017821)

Comment: @HamZa I always fear getting caught out by the dupe police, no matter how thoroughly I search - both google and stackoverflow search engines. And there you are... right on queue! ;) good answer to link to though, so thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it: Two backslashes mean you want one backslash in your string: So for the regex it looks like this: `/\{4}/` Which means you want to escape the `{`

What you need here is:

```
preg_match('/\\\\{4}/', $subject);
```

That looks for the regex like this: `/\\{4}/` and works properly.

Comment: weird though that a double \ escapes the {

Comment: this is the answer which works best for me. many thanks colburton.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
preg_match('/(?:\\\\){2}/',$subject, $m);
```

It matches 4 backslashes.

Comment: thx M42. I haven't tested it yet, but I don't doubt you (I will test it shortly). Are you able to explain why a non-capturing group is needed in this context please?

Comment: @dewd: Not sure :) but without grouping the quantifier `{4}` affect only the second backslash, so the expression is like `\\\\\` that is like a single `\` that escape the `{` and then no match.

Comment: This reads for the regex like this `/(?:\){4}/` since there is no such thing as `\)`, there is no escaping taking place, and the backslash is taken literally.

Comment: this seems to be returning false - as in error. have you tested it?

Answer (score 1):

Regex is the wrong tool when you're looking for a literal string.

```
strpos($subject, str_repeat("\\",4)) !== false
```

Comment: true, and good point, but i'm not just looking for a literal string. to keep it simple, i've just given you the part of the regex that's failing. you don't need the rest of it.