# need regexp to help me extract data from within double-quotes

Tags: regex, perl

I have sought the answer to this question here in stackoverflow but can't get acceptable results.  (Sorry!)

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
share "SHARE1" "/path/to/some/share" umask=022 maxusr=4294967295 netbios=SOMECIFSHOST
share "SHARE2" "/path/to/a/different/share with spaces in the dir name" umask=022 maxusr=4294967295 netbios=ANOTHERCIFSHOST
```

... from which I need to extract the values inside double-quotes. In other words, I'd like to get something like this:

```
share,SHARE1,/path/to/some/share/,umask=022,maxusr=4294967295,netbios=SOMECIFSHOST
share,SHARE2,/path/to/a/different/share with spaces in the dir name,umask=022,maxusr=4294967295,netbios=ANOTHERCIFSHOST
```

The tricky part I've found is in trying to extract the data inside quotes.  Suggestions made here have not worked for me, so I'm guessing I'm just doing it wrong.  I also need to extract BOTH values from each line's double-quoted strings, not just the first one; I figure the remaining stuff could easily be parsed by splitting on whitespace.

In case it's relevant, I'm running this on a RHEL box and I need to pull it out with a regexp using Perl.

Thx!

Comment: I fail to see the difference between the input and the expected output which just seams to be comma seperated with quotes removed...

Comment: Just use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18217486) and then strip the quotes ?

Comment: inside quotes, are literal quotes escaped with a backslash or an other quote (i.e. "abc\"def" or "abc""def")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

if literal quotes inside quotes are escaped with a backslash: `share "SHA \" RE1" ...`

```
$str =~ s/(?|"((?>[^"\\]++|\\{2}|\\.)*)"|()) /$1,/gs;
```

if literal quotes are escaped with an other quote: `share "SHA "" RE1" ...`

```
$str =~ s/(?|"((?>[^"]++|"")*)"|()) /$1,/g;
```

if you are absolutly sure that there is no escaped quote between quotes in all your data:

```
$str =~ s/(?|"([^"]*)"|()) /$1,/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to treat your data as a CSV file and use [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.02/CSV_XS.pm) to parse it, setting the separator character to a space:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, sep_char => ' ' } )
  or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "data.txt" or die "data.txt: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    print join ',', @$row;
    print "\n";
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;
```

Output on your dataset:

```
share,SHARE1,/path/to/some/share,umask=022,maxusr=4294967295,netbios=SOMECIFSHOST
share,SHARE2,/path/to/a/different/share with spaces in the dir name,umask=022,maxusr=4294967295,netbios=ANOTHERCIFSHOST
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
[^\" ]*
```

It selects every char but the quotation marks and the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, you say one thing in the text but the example says something different, annyway, try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my @matches = $_ =~ /"(.*?)"/g;
  print "@matches\n";
}

__DATA__
share "SHARE1" "/path/to/some/share" umask=022 maxusr=4294967295 netbios=SOMECIFSHOST
share "SHARE2" "/path/to/a/different/share with spaces in the dir name" umask=022 maxusr=4294967295 netbios=ANOTHERCIFSHOST
```

output:

```
$ ./p.pl 
SHARE1 /path/to/some/share
SHARE2 /path/to/a/different/share with spaces in the dir name
```

Comment: Pretty sure at the very least that regex should be `/"(.*?)"/g` or `/"([^"]*)"/g`, to avoid greedy matching...

Answer (score 0):

```
my $str = 'share "SHARE1" "/path/to/some/share" umask=022 maxusr=4294967295 netbios=SOMECIFSHOST';
$str =~ s/"?\s*"\s*/,/g;
print $str;
```

This regex replaces like below:
"space" = ,
"space = ,
space" = ,
"" = ,

Comment: Thanks, added. My Perl's YAPE::Regex::Explain module is not installing on my pc. Otherwise I could have explained this in a better way.

Comment: @sabujhassan You mean something like [this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) :P ?

Comment: @HamZa indeed. I should bookmark this until i install the module. Thanks a looooooot :D

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
while(<>){  
    my @a = split /\s+\"|\"\s+/ , $_;      # split on any spaces + ", or any " + spaces
    for my $item ( @a ) {   
        if ( $item =~ /\"/ ) {          # if there's a quote, remove
            $item =~ s/\"//g;               
        } elsif ( $item !~ /\"/ ){      # else just replace spaces with comma
            $item =~ s/\s+/,/g; 
        }               
    }
    print join(",", @a);
    print "\n"; 
}
```

output:

```
share,SHARE1,/path/to/some/share,umask=022,maxusr=4294967295,netbios=SOMECIFSHOST,
share,SHARE2,/path/to/a/different/share with spaces in the dir name,umask=022,maxusr=4294967295,netbios=ANOTHERCIFSHOST,
```

Leave it to you to remove the last comma :)