# PHP Regex for multiple parantheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string which looks like this:

```
43.3433443 25.3434334), (43.32424432 25.435345345, 43.21313123, 25.32432423423), (43.123123123 25.344234234, 43.1234123123 25.23213123))
```

I need to extract everything that is between ( and ) as well as ( and )) with preg_match_all

I have the following regex, which works for extracting everything between ( and ) but not ( and ))

```
preg_match_all('/\), \(([A-Za-z0-9., ]+?)\)/', $data[$x], $inner);
```

I've tried using:

```
preg_match_all('/\), \(([A-Za-z0-9., ]+?)\)|\), \(([A-Za-z0-9., ]+?)\)\)/', $data[$x], $inner);
```

and:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=\), \(([A-Za-z0-9., ]+?)\))(?=\), \(([A-Za-z0-9., ]+?)\)\))/', $data[$x], $inner);
```

But none of them have worked. How would I go about to include both cases?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention, the string contains numbers within multiple starting and ending parentheses that I don't want, i.e. two parantheses ---> (( numbers here ))) <---3 parantheses

Comment: Euh, that's some crazy input ... Why don't you [just do](http://regex101.com/r/fJ4lR5) `\([^)]*\){1,2}` ?

Comment: Do you only need the numbers? Then, `preg_match_all('/\d+\.\d+/', $str, $matches);` should do the job: https://eval.in/93503

Comment: @HamZa - post that as an answer, it works.

Comment: Looks nice, and is way more efficient than my version of it, but alas, it only matches between ( and ), not between ( and ))

Comment: @ComFreek - I will check it out, I need the commas as well.

Comment: @user2973474 I sometimes "sense" [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) ...

Comment: @HamZa, not at all. Honestly, I just have no experience whatsoever with regex and I wouldn't ask for help if I hadn't been on this for hours now.

Comment: @user2973474 By chameleon question I mean that it changes. Do you know how tiresome it is to edit a [detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18217486) ? Anyways, let's make it clear: Does your first example really not start with `(` ? Could you add some clear input and expected output ? What happens when using `(((( 1, 3, 10)))))`?

Comment: updated my answer to your last edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following regex:

```
([^()]+?)\)
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/zL5tV4)**

PHP code:

```
preg_match_all('/([^()]+?)\)/', $data[$x], $inner);
```

**Regex for your last update**:

```
([^()]+?)\)(?![)]{2,})
```

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/uR1oD8)

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong in this, but `()` can be found in `())`, so why not just look for `()` and be done:

```
<?php
$str = '43.3433443 25.3434334), (43.32424432 25.435345345, 43.21313123, 25.32432423423), (43.123123123 25.344234234, 43.1234123123 25.23213123))';

preg_match_all("/\((.*?)\)/",$str,$matches);

echo '<pre>',print_r($matches),'</pre>';
```

Comment: This doesn't work (I've not downvoted, would have done the same and I'm currently unsure why it doesn't work)

Comment: This would work except, I forgot to mention (Sorry), the string contains some numbers within brackets I don't want, i.e. (( numbers here )))